# Why does Python interpret this variable as a int if I initialize it as a string?

Tags: python, class, typeerror, self

While working on a school project. I ran into this error

```
>>> y = tokens.numberToken('1.23')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tokens.py", line 10, in __init__
    self._value = v
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.23'
```

I traced it back to this section of code

```
class token:
    def type(self):
        return "UNDEF"
    def getValue(self):
        pass

class numberToken(token):
    _value = "0.0"
    def __init__(self, v = "0.0"):
        self._value = v
    def type(self):
        return "num"
    def getValue(self):
        try:
            r = int(_value)
        except ValueError:
            r = float(_value)
        return r
```

I realized that in getValue(self) _value should be self._value. I fixed this thinking it was probably unrelated however upon reloading the module, the code ran perfectly.

So my question is why did python try to convert the inputted string as a int, and why did changing _value to self._value in the other function fix the code?

Comment: Using the example you gave with the code you pasted does not cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your getValue is indeed wrong. To use _value in your class you need to type self._value, that way you are using _value for that instance of your class. And that's why it's working when you change it.

This way it looks for _value defined as global. Or you can pass it as argument to method when calling and use it like.

```
def getValue(self, _value):
    try:
        r = int(_value)
    except ValueError:
        r = float(_value)
    return r
```

For reference take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

This is example from documentation, where you can see how data and index are used in class.

```
class Reverse:
    """Iterator for looping over a sequence backwards."""
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = len(data)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.index == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.data[self.index]
```